# How to add an entire folder of wallpapers in KDE plasma 5

Tags: ubuntu, kde, plasma5

When changing the wallpaper in KDE plasma 5 (on Ubuntu 18.04 if that matters) there's a button that says "+ Add Image...". Which is cool if you want to add a wallpaper, but I have hundreds in a folder in Dropbox to sync to all my devices.

I cannot figure out how to add an entire folder (short of symlinking it to the default wallpaper folder), as is possible to do in pretty much every other DE either by selecting the folder or highlight-select a bunch and then open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder $HOME/.local/share/wallpapers (or download a wallpaper from "Get New Wallpapers" in the dialog which will make that folder.  Then copy or link files into $HOME/.local/share/wallpapers

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned linking files to the default folder in my question, and I can certainly do that, but I was hoping for a solution using the actual interface as that seems like a common feature of other DEs.

Comment: I think such a thing would be great, I'd also like such a feature.